# Setting TTL on Redis with Apache NiFi PutDistributedMapCache

Tags: redis, apache-nifi

Through `Apache NiFi v1.4.0`, how can we set the TTL for keys cached in Redis via the `PutDistributedMapCache` processor and the `RedisDistributedMapCacheClientService`? It seems that the TTL is set to -1 by default, so they will potentially live forever unless Redis itself clears them based on its maxmemory eviction strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think is exposed right now, but it would be a nice improvement.

Since PutDistributedMapCache is not specific to Redis, we'd either need a "Default TTL" in RedisDistributedMapCacheClientService that all keys would use, or we'd need a specific PutRedis processor that didn't go through the DMC interface and just used RedisConnectionPoolService.